# Pagination with part in php

Tags: php

I try to implement a pagination to my website in php
This is what I want
If I have 42 Pages and I am on the page 6

[1][2][3][4][5]**[6]**[7][8][9][10][20][30][40][42]

or I am on the page 23
[1][10][20][21][22]**[23]**[24][25][26][27][28][29][30][40][42]

This what I did

```
$nbPage = 42;
$actualPage = 23;

$min_part_pagination = floor($actualPage / 10)*10;
$max_part_pagination = ceil($actualPage  / 10 )*10;

$last_part_pagination = floor($nbPage /10 )*10;
$first_part_pagination = 10;

$count = 1;

for($j = 1 ; $j <= $nbPage ; $j++){

    if($j % 10){
        if($pageActuelle == $count){
            $max_part_pagination = ($max_part_pagination < $nbPage) ? $max_part_pagination : $nbPage+1;
            for($k = $min_part_pagination+1 ; $k < $max_part_pagination ; $k++ ){
                if($k == 1){
                    echo "<a href=http://dev.blablabl.fr/public_html/>".$k."</a> ";
                }else{
                    echo "<a href=http://dev.blablabl.fr/public_html/page/".$k.">".$k."</a> ";
                }
            }
        }
        elseif($count == $nbPage && $pageActuelle < $last_tranche_pagination ){
            echo "<a href=http://dev.blablabl.fr/public_html/page/".$count.">".$count."</a> ";
        }elseif($count == 1 && $pageActuelle >= $first_tranche_pagination ){
            echo "<a href=http://dev.blablabl.fr/public_html/>1</a> ";
        }
    }else{
        if($pageActuelle == $count){
            if($max_part_pagination == $max_part_pagination ){
                $max_part_pagination += 10;
            }else{
                $max_part_pagination = $last_tranche_pagination;
            }
            echo 'min_part_pagination > '.$min_part_pagination.'<br />';
            echo 'max_part_pagination > '.$max_part_pagination.'<br />';
            for($k = $min_part_pagination ; $k < $max_part_pagination ; $k++){
                echo "<a href=http://dev.blablabl.fr/public_html/page/".$k.">".$k."</a> ";
            }
        }else{
            echo "<a href=http://dev.blablabl.fr/public_html/page/".$count.">".$count."</a> "; 
        }
    }
```

My problem is If I am on the page 41 It show [40][41][42][43][44][45][46][47][48][49][50]
It doesn't stop at 42

Comment: `$max_part_pagination += 10` needs to be constrained to the upper bound.

Comment: yes I was thinking about ... but i don't think my whole code is really good btw ....